# template or partial inheritance with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, templates, partial

I'm making a client side website with only HTML+CSS+JS for my portfolio, I've been copy-pasting my header and footer in almost all the differents urls.

I would like to know if there is a way to avoid that using like a **partial or template** (as is used in Rails or Flask) but **with Vue.js**.

I mean, I want my HTML files look something like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<!--My HTML code for this file.html-->
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus et elementum ex. Etiam fermentum lacus non convallis ultrices.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: So you want to use a backend construct in a frontend framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using a Vue.js components
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html

```js
//Header.js
export default {
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  template: `
    <header>
    <p>This is a header</p>
    </header>`
}
```

```html
<!-- Any .html file -->
<body>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
  <script type="module">
    import Header from '../static/vue/Header.js'
    const { createApp } = Vue
    createApp(Header).mount('#header')
  </script>

  <div id="header"></div>

  ...

</body>
```